# ggplot2: Projecting points or distribution on a non-orthogonal (eg, -45 degree) axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, geometry, projection

The figure below is a conceptual diagram used by Michael Clark,
https://m-clark.github.io/docs/lord/index.html
to explain Lord's Paradox and related phenomena in regression.

[image]

My question is framed in this context and using `ggplot2` but it is broader in terms of geometry & graphing.

I would like to reproduce figures like this, but using actual data. I need to know:

- how to draw a new axis at the origin, with a -45 degree angle, corresponding to values of `y-x`
- how to draw little normal distributions or density diagrams, or other representations of the values `y-x` projected onto this axis.

My minimal base example uses `ggplot2`,

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)
N <- 200
group   <- rep(c(0, 1), each = N/2)
initial <- .75*group + rnorm(N, sd=.25)
final   <- .4*initial + .5*group + rnorm(N, sd=.1)
change  <- final - initial
df <- data.frame(id = factor(1:N), 
                group = factor(group, 
                               labels = c('Female', 'Male')), 
                initial, 
                final, 
                change)
#head(df)

#' plot, with regression lines and data ellipses
ggplot(df, aes(x = initial, y = final, color = group)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula  =  y~x) +
  stat_ellipse(size = 1.2) +
  geom_abline(slope  =  1, color = "black", size = 1.2) +
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(-.6, 1.2), ylim = c(-.6, 1.2)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = c(.15, .85))
```

This gives the following graph:

[image]

In geometry, the coordinates of the -45 degree rotated axes of distributions I want to portray are
(y-x), (x+y) in the original space of the plot. But how can I draw these with
`ggplot2` or other software?

An accepted solution can be vague about how the distribution of (y-x) is represented,
but should solve the problem of how to display this on a (y-x) axis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fun question! I haven't encountered it yet, but there might be a package to help do this automatically. Here's a manual approach using two hacks:

1. the `clip = "off"` parameter of the `coord_*` functions, to allow us to add annotations outside the plot area.
2. building a density plot, extracting its coordinates, and then rotating and translating those.

First, we can make a density plot of the change from initial to final, seeing a left skewed distribution:

```
(my_hist <- df %>%
    mutate(gain = final - initial) %>% # gain would be better name
    ggplot(aes(gain)) +
    geom_density())
```

[image]

Now we can extract the guts of that plot, and transform the coordinates to where we want them to appear in the combined plot:

```
a <- ggplot_build(my_hist)
rot = pi * 3/4
diag_hist <- tibble(
  x = a[["data"]][[1]][["x"]],
  y = a[["data"]][[1]][["y"]]
) %>%
  # squish
  mutate(y = y*0.2) %>%
  # rotate 135 deg CCW
  mutate(xy = x*cos(rot) - y*sin(rot),
         dens = x*sin(rot) + y*cos(rot)) %>%
  # slide
  mutate(xy = xy - 0.7,  #  magic number based on plot range below
         dens = dens - 0.7)
```

And here's a combination with the original plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = initial, y = final, color = group)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula  =  y~x) +
  stat_ellipse(size = 1.2) +
  geom_abline(slope  =  1, color = "black", size = 1.2) +
  coord_fixed(clip = "off", 
              xlim = c(-0.7,1.6),
              ylim = c(-0.7,1.6), 
              expand = expansion(0)) +
  annotate("segment", x = -1.4, xend = 0, y = 0, yend = -1.4) +
  annotate("path", x = diag_hist$xy, y = diag_hist$dens) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = c(.15, .85), 
        plot.margin = unit(c(.1,.1,2,2), "cm"))
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Some deep ggplot2 magic shown here. Whoever heard of `ggplot_build()`?

Comment: Thanks, edited with that clearer name.